# How publish object by Stream to a sibling component which is not yet created?

Tags: dart, angular-dart

I have one view which loads some data and needs to pass it to a sibling view. I'm trying to use shared injectable service + Stream `add/listen`.

I have read https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service and many other similar questions but my case is different.

In my case, sibling is not created when I do `service.streamController.add` and thus, nothing happens when I navigate to sibling, it has listen method but I guess it cannot catch smth published before component started.

Comment: Can you load the data in the parent component and pass it via @Input() to both children?

Comment: They are already topmost level components. Well, I can do it in main page but just don't want to break the relevance. For now I'm using injectable service with null check and fetch again if there are not any data.